# Strange bug in usage of abs() I encountered recently

Tags: c++, standard-library

I have C++/C mixed code which I build on

a) Visual C++ 2010 Express(Free version) on Win-7 x32.

b) Cygwin/Gcc environment installed on a Windows-7 Home premium edition x32. The gcc version 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)

c) Ubuntu 10.04 Linux- GCC version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)

I have a code as below(Its a member function for my user defined class) which computes absolute value of the passed object myhalf-

```
myhalf::myhalfabs(myhalf a)
{
    float tmp;   
    tmp = abs(a.value); //This abs is from math.h :-  float abs(float)
    return tmp;
}
```

This is working perfectly as desired in MS - Visual C++ 2010. abs() of -ve nos were returned correctly as +ve nos having same value.
Strangely when I built this code on b) Cygwin/gcc environment & c) Linux-gcc 4.4.3 mentioned above, I was getting junk output. So fired up gdb, and after lot of sweat and 'binary-search approach' on the code to decide where it started going wrong, I hit this piece of code as shown above :

```
tmp = abs(a.value);
```

which was behaving strangely under cygwin/gcc.

For -ve numbers abs() was returning 0(zero).  WTF??

Then as a work around, avoided calling abs() from stdlib, and coded my own abs as below:

```
myhalf::myhalfabs(myhalf a)
{
    float tmp;
    unsigned int tmp_dbg;
    // tmp = abs(a.value);
    tmp_dbg = *(unsigned int*)(&a.value);
    tmp_dbg = tmp_dbg & 0x7FFFFFFF;
    tmp = *(float*)(&tmp_dbg);

    return tmp;
}
```

This worked fine on cygwin/gcc & linux-gcc and output was as desired, And of course it worked fine on MS-Visual C++ 2010.

This is the whole Makefile for the cygwin/gcc and linux-gcc builds, I use. Just if anyone supspects something fishy there:-

```
OBJS= <all my obj files listed here explicitly>

HEADERS= <my header files here>
CFLAGS= -Wall
LIBS= -lm
LDFLAGS= $(LIBS)

#MDEBUG=1
ifdef MDEBUG
CFLAGS += -fmudflap
LDFLAGS += -fmudflap -lmudflap
endif

myexe:    $(OBJS)
    g++ $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o myexe

%.o:    %.cpp $(HEADERS) Makefile
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    rm -f myexe $(OBJS)
```

---

1] What is going on here? What is the root cause of this strange bug?

2] Am i using some old version of gcc on cygwin which has this issue as known bug or something?

3] Is this function float abs(float) known to be deprecated or something with a newer version superseding it?

Any pointers are useful.

Comment: It would be useful if you created a small testcase, so that everyone can take the snippet, compile unmodified, and see for himself what you mean.

Comment: The `abs()` function generally returns an `int`, and you're assigning it to a `float`.  Are you sure this isn't the root of your problems?

Comment: do you get the same behavior with `fabs`?

Comment: I agree with larsks - there's a `fabs()` function specifically for floats.  Does it help to use that instead?

Comment: @littleadv - Will try with fabs on Monday. Will update. larsks - see math.h . abs has can faccept float return float.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`math.h` has the C version of `abs` which operates on `int`s. Use `<cmath>` for the C++ overloads or use `fabs()` for the C floating point version.

Comment: Yes , I see I am including math.h (deprecated use to include C libraries in C++ code, my bad) Will try cmath.h or cstdlib, as also suggested Mark.B

Comment: @goldenmean: cmath, not cmath.h. standard c++ headers have no extension

Comment: @PlasmaHH - Yean, sorry. Its  <cmath> .

Answer (score 15):

First, [abs()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/abs) takes and returns an `int`. You should use [fabs()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fabs), which takes and returns a floating-point value.

Now, the `abs()` you're ending up calling is actually a GCC [built-in function](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuexts.html#SEC104), which returns an `int`, but apparently accepts a `float` argument and returns `0` in that case.

Comment: It will actually cast the `float` to an `int` and truncate the value.  That is 0.001 gets truncated to 0, 1.001 gets truncated to 1, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Almost certainly what's happening is that in your MSVC case it's picking up the C++ `abs` float overload (which is probably being brought into the global namespace for some reason or other). And then in g++ it's NOT picking up the C++ version (which isn't implicitly imported into the global namespace) but the C version that works on and returns an `int` which is then truncating the output to zero.

If you `#include <cmath>` and use `std::abs` it should work fine on all your platforms.