# Can't make a standard function forbidden using a preprocessor statement?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Trying to fix this issue: [C++ How can I prevent my team developers from using integer version of abs by mistake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499142/c-how-can-i-prevent-my-team-developers-from-using-integer-version-of-abs-by-mi?noredirect=1#comment64398768_38499142) by using macro to make `abs` function not usable anymore.

If I compile a code containing `myabs(3);` with g++ option `-Dmyabs=abs` it compiles (`myabs` being replaced by `abs`), fine.

Now, if I compile a code containing `abs(3);` with g++ option `-Dabs=forbidden` it compiles too...why it does not report that `forbidden` is unknown? Looks like `abs` is not replaced by `forbidden` during pre-processing...why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looks like abs is not replaced by forbidden during pre-processing...why?

At least the standard library headers that I use (libstdc++) which define `::abs`, undefine your macro:

> ```
> // Get rid of those macros defined in <math.h> in lieu of real functions.
> #undef abs
> #undef div
> // ...
> ```

Your headers could be doing the same thing. Given such undefinition, it is indeed impossible to ban such function using a preprocessor macro.

Comment: If it is guarded by include guards you could force its inclusion with the -include cmath compiler argument then define the abs macro (untried)

Comment: Good answer: `abs` is replaced by `forbidden` before I include `math`, not after, so one must do `#undef abs`